# ODBC Error "Cannot launch MYOB" when data file is on a network drive on Windows 10

Tags: odbc, myob

My client has a new PC running Windows 10

An add on solution which makes use of the ODBC driver works if the data file is on C:
However if the data file is on a network drive the ODBC access fails with error "Cannot launch MYOB"

The old Windows XP computer still works.

MYOBP.exe is located in C:\Premier19  and marked to run as administrator for all users.

I set compatibility to be Windows 7 and disabled UAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I also needed to run the add on solution as Administrator.
Also the data file location needed to be referred to using a UNC path rather than mapped drive.